# How to do while loop using condition over vector of objects

Tags: python, while-loop

In python, if I have a vector of objects `V` with local variable (boolean) `t`, where `t` is initially set to `False`. I'd like to do a while loop until all objects have `t` set to `True`... how could I do that?

i.e. --- here's a pseudocode of what am thinking of..

```
[o.t. = False for o in V] # initially all are false
while [o.t != True for o in V]:

... do stuff that will make o.t True eventually...
```

Comment: The first line is not in Python. You cannot have assignments in a list comprehension. Other than that, read about the function `any()`.

Comment: I was writing it in pseudocode style

Comment: Why would one ask a Python question in a pseudocide style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to your desired state is `all` built-in function. As you had not described the class from which the objects were created I used a tiny class to simulate your situation:

```
import random
class customClass:
    def __init__(self, condition=False):
        self.condition = condition


v = [customClass() for _ in range(5)]

print([obj.condition for obj in v])
# Prints: [False, False, False, False, False]

while not all([obj.condition for obj in v]):

    #do stuff that sometimes changes the state of condition 
    # Here I randomly select an object and set its condition to true
    o = random.choice(v)
    o.condition = True

print([obj.condition for obj in v])
# Prints: [True, True, True, True, True]
```

Note that the number of iterations is not 5 and the while loop continues until all of the elemets of the list fed to it are true. You can check it's documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).